# Legacy Scanner; can I run XP inside of VMware or VirtualBox for support?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, virtual-machine

I have a legacy hp scanner that I am trying to run on my windows 7 machine.  I've explored VirtualPC, but it appears that my processor doesn't support that.  I'm now exploring other  options.

I'm wondering if I can run VMware or Virtual Box and install a copy of Windows XP in it, and then install the scanner drivers in the virtual system.  To scan, I would start the virtual copy of XP and run the scan from within there.

Thoughts?

Comment: Off course you can!
Can you show us the error that you get using Windows XP Mode?

Comment: "Windows Virtual PC requires hardware-assisted virtualization. There is no hardware-assisted virtualization support in the system".  I've been doing some research and it does not appear that my CPU supports virtualization.

Comment: You should install this update in order to can install without validate the hardware assited virtualization technology http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/es-es/details.aspx?FamilyID=837F12AA-1D37-464E-AE59-20C9ECBEBAF6

Comment: How is the scanner connected, network or USB?

Comment: it is connected via usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final solution folks:

Virtual PC's performance was poor.  It was so poor that it was unusable. I deemed this to be a dead end.  It *may* be possible to get good performance out of Virtual PC, but I don't know.  I knew that VMware has good performance in general, so I gave that a shot.

In just a few hours, I had a copy of VMware Player installed, XP installed, Scanner software drivers installed, and I've just done my first scan.

Task Completed.

Virtual PC seemed promising, but there were FAR TOO MANY STEPS involved.  I had to download three different pieces of software, then there were some convoluded steps to get sharing working.  Once sharing was working, Virtual PC took up 100% of the CPU, making the host system unusable.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of your question you get how to Install Windows XP Mode. After you Install the scanner using Windows XP Mode, you should install the Scanned in the XP.

The Scanner will be automaticaaly published on your Windows 7 OS.

Comment: I tried to run the update but it said "this update is not applicable to your computer"  I am running windows 7 ultimate with all SP and updates.

Comment: Maybe I give you the Update of another version or platform. Go to http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx select your settings and donwload the third file. The step number 4. These is the update.

Comment: It looks like I was able to get virtual pc working, but I'm noticing virtual pc's performance is so poor, I might have to go with VMware or VirtualBox just based on performance.  Will be working on this later today.